# Show check box value in a textbox

Tags: jquery, dropdown

What I'm trying to achieve is, I have a checkbox with a value="" When the checkbox is checked the value should show in a text box.

```
<input type="text" id="results">
<div id="multiselect-drop">
<input type="checkbox" value="Testing the textbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="Testing 2 the textbox">
</div>
<script>
$('#multiselect-drop input').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $li = $('<li></li>');
    $li.text(this.value);
    $('#results').append($li);
  }
  else {
    $('li:contains('+this.value+')', '#results').remove();
  }
});
</script>
```

EDIT:
What if I have multiple checkboxes? Can I show all checked Item in the text box with comma separated?

Comment: Why not simply do `$('#results').val(this.value);` ? why you are appending li to textbox ?

Answer (score 2):

You should not append an `li` element into an `input`

try with this code:

```
$('#multiselect-drop input').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#results').val(this.value);
  } else {
    $('#results').val("");
  }
});
```

You can also move the `if` statement if you want:

```
$('#multiselect-drop input').change(function() {
  $('#results').val((this.checked ? this.value : ""));
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#multiselect-drop input').change(function() {
  var s = $('#multiselect-drop input:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(',');
  $('#results').val((s.length > 0 ? s : ""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="results">
<div id="multiselect-drop">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Testing the textbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="another textbox">
</div>
```

Comment: This is really helpful, but what if there multiple checkboxes with different values? How can I show all values in the textbox comma separated?

Answer (score 1):

May you can use this

```js
$("#multiselect-drop input").change(
 function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $("#results").val($(this).val());
  }
  else {
    $("#results").val("");
  }
 }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="results">
<div id="multiselect-drop">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Testing the textbox">
</div>
```